# How do I debug when GAE works slow in local development but works fine when uploaded to Google?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am running under Windows7 locally.  I have tried both Python 2.5 and Python 2.7.2.  It just seems to stall a lot locally.  All I am using is authentication and database.  I get very inconsistent results locally.  I upload the app to the server and it works.  Sometimes when I am on a database page I will hit Refresh 10 times and 3 of the times the browser will just keep spinning.

I am using the latest GAE 1.5.3.  (I was having the same issue with older 1.4.x version as well.)

Any ideas on what to try or what to look into?

Comment: I had the same problem with Windows 7 + GAE dev server. Solution? I switched to Ubuntu.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere in the docs that the development environment isn't optimized, unlike the production environment.

Comment: The development server has had performance issues due to the way it calculates new indexes and outputs logs (and other reasons). There are a few discussions about this on the GAE Google Group. The latest pre-release (1.6.1) seems to have fixed many of the performance issues. Give it a try (or wait a week for the full 1.6.1) and see if that fixes your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to switch to SQLLite for your local Datastore, you can do this by using the following option:

```
dev_appserver.py --use_sqlite
```

Another good practice would be to use the High Replication datastore simulation flag to give you a good idea how an application configured to use the High replication datastore will do in production, you can achieve the following by suing:

```
dev_appserver.py --high_replication
```

For the full documentation please check the following [Link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Using_the_Datastore)

Hope this helps!